# CodeIgniter - Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name - using strcmp

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently using codeIgniter 3. I created a registration page with username, password, password confirmation and email. For compare the two string, I used strcmp() function. Now, the problem is when I put something like

```
password = "moon";
confirmation_password = "moon";
```

It work without any problems. Logically you'll tell me :)
Otherwise, when I put something like

```
password = "moon";
confirmation_password = "something else";
```

Now it still work with show me the appropriate error message. Logically again you'll tell me. Except that another error message pop:

```
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password confirmation.(check_information)
```

I don't understand how this error message could pop only when the confirmation_password variable doesn't match with password variable.
Here's my code

```
function index()
{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmation_password', 'Password confirmation', 'trim|required|callback_check_information');
}

function check_information($confirmation_password)
{
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    if (strcmp($password, $confirmation_password))
        {
            echo 'password and confirmation password doesn\'t match';
            return FALSE;
        }

}
```

Does anyone can tell if is there something wrong in my code ?
I voluntarily show you a part of my code for avoid to make my post too long.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return with boolean in both cases, and not echo the message, set it:

```
function check_information($confirmation_password)
{
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    if (strcmp($password, $confirmation_password))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_information', 'password and confirmation password doesn\'t match');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably `return TRUE` not neccessary, its checking against `FALSE`, but that's how suggested...

Comment: Thank you ! it work now :)
But can you explain me why couldn't I use echo ?

Comment: Welcome! :) Codeigniter call a custom function checks the return value, and check is the custom message set for that field. And if your print `validation_errors()` your message won't be a part of it, it will be separated probably.

Comment: Since strcmp() function returns 0 if truthy or in other words if strings are equal, it would be better to check this way:  `if (strcmp($password, $confirmation_password) === 0)`. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution, try this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmation_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');
```